# Influxdb request on time

Tags: python, sql, sql-like, influxdb

I have a problem with my request to Influxdb, if I request with now() time parameters it's work fine but when I try to request with variable parameters it's doesn't work.

that is ok :

```
"SELECT * FROM \"%s\" 
WHERE session_id = '%s' AND time > now() - 10s AND time < now() - 9s 
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 25" %(table, session_id)
```

that is not :

```
"SELECT * FROM \"%s\" 
WHERE session_id = '%s' AND time > \'%U\' AND time < \'%U\' 
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 25" %(table, session_id, date_inf, date_sup)
```

date_inf and date_sup are timestamp nanosecond.

Here is the doc and we can see at the example 3 what I want to do:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/data_exploration/#time-syntax

If someone can help he is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM \"%s\" WHERE session_id = **\'%s\'** AND time > begin
AND time < end + 1s** ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 25" %(table,
session_id)
```

In this case "begin" and "end" are time variables in UTC format ('2018-02-20T04:05:25Z' etc.) 
To specify requests for influxDB you can use Data Explorer of Chronograf.